# Function is undefined when passed to plugin

Tags: jquery

I wrote a plugin to do some validation, and am passing a function in the plugin's options, but the function that I am passing is coming in as undefined and I am not sure why

in the document ready I have the plugin being called

```
$('#btnSaveBlade').on('click', function () {
    $('#BladeInputs').AW_Validation({
        container: '#BladeInputs',
        attribute: 'aw-is-required',
        complete: SaveNewClient("Client")
    });
});
```

Here is part of the plugin

```
$.fn.AW_Validation = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        container: null,
        attribute: null,
        //complete: null, // Callback function on successful completion <- didn't work
        complete: function(){},// Callback function on successful completion <- doesn't work either
        summary: null,
        notification: null
    }, options);
    ...
}
```

I am not sure what I am going wrong or what is wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `SaveNewClient(...)` to the plugin you are actually calling it, since it probably returns `undefined` thats what you get

Try changing:

```
$('#BladeInputs').AW_Validation({
    container: '#BladeInputs',
    attribute: 'aw-is-required',
    complete: SaveNewClient("Client")
});
```

For

```
$('#BladeInputs').AW_Validation({
    container: '#BladeInputs',
    attribute: 'aw-is-required',
    complete: function(){ SaveNewClient("Client"); }
});
```

Or Better yet

```
$('#BladeInputs').AW_Validation({
    container: '#BladeInputs',
    attribute: 'aw-is-required',
    complete: SaveNewClient.bind(null, "Client")
});
```

**EDIT:** Further explanation

Expressions are evaluated from inside out, just as if you ran `{a: 1 + 1}` then `1 + 1` would be evaluated first, resulting in `{a: 2}`

The same would happen with a function like the following:

```
function onePlusOne() { return 1 + 1; }
```

Lets look at the following example:

```
$.yourPlugin(
       $.extend({ a: onePlusOne() }, { b: 2}))
```

Then `onePlusOne()` would run first evaluating to `2`, then `$.extend({ a: onePlusOne() }, { b: 2})` is evaluated to `{a: 2, b: 2}` which is what `$.yourPlugin()` recieves

Now imagine `onePlusOne()` didn't return a value, in that case javascript would return `undefined` and thats what your `complete` ended up being passed

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. I do have a question though, when you explained what was happening with my code about the function being called when its being passed, why is that?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer to have more room for an explanation, hope it helps